# How to ensure lines are always displayed in groups of 3?

Tags: window, hooks, scrolling

I am writing [a major-mode](https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode/) which displays a list to the user. It is similar to [`tabulated-list-mode`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/tabulated-list-mode), except each entry takes up 3 lines, as opposed to just one:

```
  0   0 Ctrl-} key in emacs 
        5m ago [keymap] 

  6   1 Set the background of org-exported <code> blocks according to theme 
        40m ago [org-mode] [org-export] [html] 

  7  10 How to switch between windows quickly? 
        79m ago [window] [navigation] 

  3   1 Org-mode: Exclude specific headlines from TOC when exporting 
        96m ago [org-mode] [org-export]
```

I've defined all movement keys so that the user navigates by entry
instead of by line, but there's one thing I can't quite fix. Whenever
the window is split below or above, there's a decent chance that the first line in the (original) window will *not* be the first line of an entry. This happens because the buffer is scrolled to make sure point is still visible after the split.

Here's an example of what I might get when splitting (note this can
happen even if I ensure the size is a multiple of 3).

```
        5m ago [keymap] 

  6   1 Set the background of org-exported <code> blocks according to theme 
        40m ago [org-mode] [org-export] [html] 

  7  10 How to switch between windows quickly?
```

**I would like this buffer to reposition itself, every time the window
  size changes, so as to ensure the *first visible line is always a
  (multiple of 3) minus 1*.**
*(Whether it scrolls up or down is irrelevant, as long as `point` is not moved.)*

So the example above should display something like.

```
  0   0 Ctrl-} key in emacs 
        5m ago [keymap] 

  6   1 Set the background of org-exported <code> blocks according to theme 
        40m ago [org-mode] [org-export] [html]
```

Is this possible?

*EDIT:* Note, I'd like to scroll the window as little as possible---always 1 or 2 lines.

Comment: "Whenever the window is split below or above, there's a 2/3 chance that the first line in the window will not be the first line of an entry." Just to clarify: Do you want the buffer in the *original* window to reposition itself? Or do you want the repositioning to affect the buffer in the newly created window?

Comment: @itsjeyd Original is what I need. Although, I think both should be simultaneously possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative function that respects the major mode and works with `window-size-change-functions`:

```el
(defun reposition-buffer (frame)
  (when (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode) ; Substitute name of your major-mode here
    (save-excursion
      (let* ((current-line (line-number-at-pos (point)))
             (offset (mod current-line 3)))
        (cond ((= offset 0) (previous-line 2))
              ((= offset 2) (previous-line 1))
              (t nil))
        (recenter-top-bottom 0)))))

(add-hook 'window-size-change-functions 'reposition-buffer)
```

The logic is as follows (`<n>` denotes a line number):

```
<1> 0   0 Ctrl-} key in emacs 
<2>       5m ago [keymap] 
<3>
<4> 6   1 Set the background of org-exported <code> blocks according to theme 
<5>       40m ago [org-mode] [org-export] [html]
<6>
```

- If point is in line `1` or `4` (`n modulo 3 == 1`) , we don't have to move, as each of these lines starts a new entry.
- If point is in line `2` or `5` (`n modulo 3 == 2`), we have to move up *one* line to get to the beginning of the corresponding entry.
- If point is in line `3` or `6` (`n modulo 3 == 0`), we have to move up *two*
  lines to get to the beginning of the corresponding entry.

As a last step, we recenter the current line to the top of the window.

Comment: Nice.  Minor suggestion: change your lowercase `l` variable to `line` (or something), as lowercase `l` looks a lot like a the number `1`.

Comment: @Dan Yes, you're right! Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer. But it always scrolls until point is at the top, and I'd really like to scroll as little as possible. I'll probably end up combining the two. :-)

Comment: @Malabarba I'm not sure what you mean by "it always scrolls until point is at the top"? For me, point stays in the same spot. Are you referring to the entry point is in?

Comment: @itsjeyd Sorry if I expressed poorly. The position of point doesn't move in the buffer (that's great :-). However, if point is far from the top of the window, the buffer is scrolled all the way up, until the current entry is at the top of the window. I would like to just scroll up by just 0, 1, or 2 lines. Still, doing this is a very trivial extension from your code, and your answer explained what I needed, so I'm accepting it anyway.

Comment: @Malabarba I see :) Just out of curiosity, what did you add/change to make my code fully address your use case? I was experimenting with `move-to-window-line` (inside of `save-excursion`), but that didn't seem to do the trick...

Answer (score 3):

The following function checks a window to see if it's top line is a multiple of three, and scrolls if needed to make it so:

```
(defun first-window-line-in-threes (&optional window)
  "Make sure that the first line in the window is a multiple of
three (0-based rather than 1-based).  Scroll if necessary, but
leave point where it is."
  (interactive)
  (let ((offset (mod (1- (line-number-at-pos (window-start window))) 3)))
    (unless (zerop offset)
      (scroll-down offset)
      (forward-line offset))))
```

It looks like the [relevant hooks/functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Hooks.html) are `window-configuration-change-hook` and `window-size-change-functions`.  Using the former almost works, but it seems to respond to curious events like minibuffer resizing.  The latter requires a bit of fiddling, and I hadn't quite gotten it right before dashing out the door.